# Guidewire - PCF: Cannot have any text content

Tags: xml, guidewire, gosu

Error states:

```
PCF: Cannot have any text content
```

Caused on a PCF file. The error targets a specific line at the PCF ID. No other description as to why it may be erroring.

Comment: what PCF file? what line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that there is stray text between tags. Recommend searching and removing the typo. Utilizing an IDE other than Studio, such as VS Code, may help identify the error.

Answer (score 3):

PCF editors have both a "Page Configuration" & "Text" view. View the appropriate line number of the .pcf-file's XML in the latter view. You can fix in the IDE using this view.

[image: PCF Text View]